# MVC Controller Action Result method call works, But view page doesn't appears

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, controller

My project contains a view. which contain few text boxes and a button.
Button click will send the all text box value to controller method.

```
$('#btnNext').click(function () {
            var dataToPost =
            {
                FirstName: $('#txt_FirstName').val(), LastName: $('#txt_lastName').val(), Email: $('#txt_emailID').val(),
                MobileNumber: $('#txt_mobileNumber').val(), AddressLine1: $('#txt_addressLine1').val(), AddressLine2: $('#txt_addressLine2').val(),
                Nationality: $('#ddlCountry').val(), State: $('#ddlCountry').prop('selectedIndex'), City: $('#ddlCountry').val(),
                GenderTypeID: $('#ddlGender').val(), Pincode: $('#txtPincode').val()
            } 

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Main/getCompetitorDetails",
                data: dataToPost,
                type: "POST",
                success: function (e) {
                    debugger;
                    alert(e);
```

Which is perfectly calling the method "getCompetitorDetails" in Main Controller.
Then the method call is calling the Payment view

```
public ActionResult getCompetitorDetails(CompetitorInformation cI) => View("Payment");

public ActionResult Payment() => View();
```

But the view is not showing. 
When debugging , After the method call, The next step it is going to the Payment.cshtml page. Here:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
```

Then nothing happens.

I didn't set any layout page as of now.
So i made it to null.
AM i missing anything here?

Comment: When  you are making ajax call to get the view, you should append that view to the section of your html page. In success callback, you should have logic to append the html.

Comment: @AkashKC i am making ajax call only to send data to controller, not to get the view. I am calling controller method to show the view.